# table sorting in angular 6 application

Tags: html, angular

I am developing angular 6 application, wherein I have one table with few columns into it, now I need to sort the table column when the user clicks on upward or downward arrow there, I **don't** want to use angular material in this case.  any help on this?

Data would be an array and will bind to HTML

```
  <div class='table_row' *ngFor="let data of myOrder; let i=index">
```

and finally, data coming from the array is being bound to each cell or column.

```
<div class='table_small'>
        <div class='table_cell'>Order</div>
        <div class='table_cell'>
          <p>{{data.executionDate | date: 'dd/MM/yy hh:mm'}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The table column above is just for demonstration purpose the actual values are of string and number only not the date.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Your question is how to order an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `onClick` event on your up and down arrows and implement your own custom sorting.

for example HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th (onClick)="sortNumberColumn()>Number Column</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Component:

```
public ascNumberSort = true;
public sortNumberColumn() {
    this.ascNumberSort = !this.ascNumberSort;
    if(this.ascNumberSort) {
        this.numberColumn.sort((a, b) => a - b); // For ascending sort
    } else {
        this.numberColumn.sort((a, b) => b - a); // For descending sort
    }
}
```

The above is just an example, I have not compiled this code. It's just to give you an understanding.

Comment: this.numberColumn would of what ? or like how do you want to make it happen ?

Comment: So that would be your property you want to sort (the function I wrote above is a numerical sort). So it would be something like `this.myOrder.orderNumber`

Comment: thanks for your reply, In my HTML I am looping through data of myorder where in each row of one data row so I really dont understand how I will bind back to HTML.

Comment: So you have defined your table headers before your loop, that's where you would apply the onClick event handlers. Since Angular has 2 way binding back to your model, when you sort, it should also apply in the frontend due to Angulars change detection

Comment: Ok,I am working on this, but meanwhile can you please tell me how the approach would change if I need to sort based on string and not on number.

Comment: to sort based on a string you can just use `.sort()`, to do descending just `.sort()` then `.reverse()`

Comment: so here, this.myOrder.orderNumber I cant use directly since it is array, so do you mean I have to use something like this.myOrder[0].orderNumber? if you are referring this way then I dont think this will help.

Comment: You have not given enough detail about your model for me to help with you specific code issue. I have just provided a solution for custom sorting on a table.

Comment: In your case the function would be called `sortOrderNumber()` and you would just do a object based sort based on your property

Comment: Yes as I am sorry  for that as I stated the incoming is array and that is why I am looping through using *ngFor and creating cell wise data into table.

Comment: @JamieRees Your answer was very helpful for me. Thank you very much!
Just few things: in doesnt work for me (onClick) just on (click).
And this line `this.ascNumberSort = !this.ascNumberSort;` wants me to click twice to unclick it and only then descend it. So I replaced it with `this.ascNumberSort = false`